# How display specific line in HDFS file which contains special string

Tags: hadoop

I have these lines

```
DIS_CD_RLT_PSE,D,,177959,10.425719262087393
DIS_CD_RLT_PSE,E,,811061,47.5159687929684
DIS_CD_RLT_PSE,I,,113424,6.6449394612410755
DIS_CD_RLT_PSE,M,,404023,23.66966758313058
DIS_CD_RLT_PSE,P,,28083,1.6452411737377726
DIS_CD_RLT_PSE,U,,142155,8.32814368310697
DIS_CD_RLT_PSE,Z,,30218,1.7703200437278073
```

which are located here

```
/hdfs/data/t11/t111/t1/t/z/InterfacePublique/
```

I need a hadoop command that can display only the line :

```
DIS_CD_RLT_PSE,I,,113424,6.6449394612410755
```

Given by **DIS_CD_RLT_PSE** and **I** string.

I tried like this :

```
Hadoop fs -ls /hdfs/data/t11/t111/t1/t/z/InterfacePublique/ | grep DIS_CD_RLT_PSE | grep I
```

But it doesn't give the needed result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to *nix, the `-ls` option lists the files and directories in a given path, it doesn't read hdfs file content. See [HDFS file system shell documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html). 
The command you're probably looking for is `-cat`:

`$ hdfs dfs -cat /hdfs/data/t11/t111/t1/t/z/InterfacePublique/* | grep "DIS_CD_RLT_PSE.*I"`

Comment: thank you for your response. But it doesn't show and display the line `DIS_CD_RLT_PSE,I,,113424,6.6449394612410755`

Comment: Hmmm... what happens if you grep for something simple, like `DIS_CD_RLT_PSE`?

Comment: @ mazaneicha, the solution is : `hadoop fs -cat /hdfs/data/t11/t111/t1/t/z/InterfacePublique/* | grep DIS_CD_RLT_PSE.*I` without quotes.

Comment: @SA2018 Thats a bit weird but thanks! Check this for example  https://serverfault.com/questions/69283/when-to-use-single-quote-double-quote-in-grep

Answer (score 1):

grep can be used if you have a limited size of files but doesn't scale when you have big data.

If you use Hive, then you could create a Hive table on this data and then write Hive Query to retrieve the required row.

For example, the above file has data where each row has 5 values separated by `,`.
We can treat we have 5 columns - `col1` , `col2`, `col3`, `col4` and `col5` of table `mytable`.
Data will be represented as :

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
col1           | col2 | col3 |    col4   | col5                |    
----------------------------------------------------------------
DIS_CD_RLT_PSE  | Z   | NULL |   30218   | 1.7703200437278073  |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

After that you can write a query like :

```
Select * from mytable where col5 == '113424'
```

You can write a MapReduce job or use another framework/tool (like Pig) which you are comfortable.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform this search on a small number of files or not very large files then below approach should work:

```
hadoop fs -ls /technology/dps/real | awk '{print $8}' | while read f; do hdfs dfs -cat $f | grep -q DIS_CD_RLT_PSE && echo $f; done
```

However, if you are doing this search on 100's of files then I would use map-reduce job or [Streaming API](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html) to do this. Above method will be really slow for large number of files.

Comment: thank you for your response but I am using Putty and it doesn't work such solution. In fact I wrote your solution in one line,But I get  -bash:  awk: `command not found
-bash: /: is a directory
grep: done: No such file or directory`

Comment: Try this, it should print the required output: `hadoop fs -ls /technology/dps/real | awk '{print $8}' | while read f; do hdfs dfs -cat $f | grep -q DIS_CD_RLT_PSE && echo $f; done`